# A problem related to arithmetico-geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

**Question:**

> Find the sum of the series: $1 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{6}{3^2} + \frac{10}{3^3} + \frac{14}{3^4} + ... = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n-2)}{3^n}$

**My doubt:**

I have taken $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{6}{3^2} + \frac{10}{3^3} + \frac{14}{3^4} + ...$ to be in A.G.P. and calculated the sum using the formula $$S_\infty=\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{d \cdot r}{(1-r)^2},$$ where $a=\frac23, r=\frac13$ and $d=4$.

I get $S_\infty=4$ and then I add $1$ to it to get the answer $5$.

But my book shows a different method with a different answer ($3$).

Please tell what is wrong with this method.

Comment: Your formula is not complete and you have also plugged in wrong values into it. The correct values should be a=2, b=1/3, d=4, r=1/3. And the correct formula is : {[ab/(1-r)] - [dbr/(1-r)^2]}

Comment: Just for objective::  $\displaystyle 1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{6}{3^2}+\frac{10}{3^3}+\frac{14}{3^4}+\cdots \cdots \infty  \approx 1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{6}{3^2}+\frac{10}{3^3}+\frac{14}{3^4}\approx 3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us make the problem more general, replacing $\frac 13$ by 
$x$. So, we have $$S=1+2x+6x^2+10x^3+14x^4+\cdots=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(4n-2)x^n$$ that is to say $$S=1+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=1+4\color{red}x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$$ $$S=1+4x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)'-2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}\implies \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ All of that makes $$S=1+\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{2x}{1-x}\implies S=\frac{3 x^2+1}{(1-x)^2}$$ Now, replace $x$ by $\frac 13$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This cleared it all :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard AGP. An AGP has the recurrence relation $u_{n+1}=r*u_n+b$, but here that isn't the case. So that's why you can't plug it into the formula for an AGP!

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you said above. Because I didn't get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use Telescoping series as well

$$\dfrac{4r-2}{3^r}=f(r+1)-f(r)$$ where $f(n)=\dfrac{a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots}{3^n}$

So that $$\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{4r-2}{3^r}=\sum_{r=1}^n(f(r+1)-f(r))=f(n+1)-f(1)$$

$$4r-2=a_0+a_1(r+1)+a_2(r+1)^2+\cdots-3\left(a_0+a_1r+a_2r^2+\cdots\right)$$

As the coefficients of $r^m$ is zero for $m\ge2\implies a_m=0\forall m\ge2$

$$4r-2=a_0+a_1(r+1)-3\left(a_0+a_1r\right)=-2a_1r+a_1-2a_0$$

Comparing the coefficients of $r,4=-2a_1\iff a_1=?$

Comparing the constants, $a_1-2a_0=-2\implies a_0=?$

For infinite sum, establish $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$$