# Sum of "intertwine" of Arithmetic & Geometric Series (to infinity)

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, geometric-series

I am just wondering is there any method to evaluate the following:

$$
2\cdot (1/2) + 3\cdot (1/4) + 4\cdot (1/8) + 5\cdot (1/16) + \ldots =\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}
$$

Frankly, I have no clue how this can be solved, I have considered finding a common ratio between terms (e.g. $2\cdot (1/2)$ and $3\cdot (1/4)$ and $4\cdot (1/8))$, but no such ratio exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use those $x$, it will be clearer without. Especially the last !

Comment: The sum on the left and the summation on the right are not the same. The LSH Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$. Also if those x's are multiplications, do not write them down like that in the summation whatsoever.

Comment: @Thorgott corrected to the best of my ability and tried to make readable, please check

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001506/a-problem-related-to-arithmetico-geometric-sequence

Comment: @gt6989b Looks good to me, except there also was a slight error in my comment. The sum should be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^n}$ or start at $n=2$ as the $n=1$ term of the current version does not actually appear on the LHS.

Comment: @Thorgott you are right, corrected the index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac22+\frac34+\frac48+\frac5{16}+\cdots=\frac22+\frac{1+2}4+\frac{1+3}8+\frac{1+4}{16}+\cdots
\\=\frac22+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots+\frac12\left(\frac22+\frac34+\frac48+\cdots\right)$$

So

$$\frac S2=\frac32.$$

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but I am just wondering how you can evaluate (1/2)(2/2 + 3/4 + 4/8 + ...) in the final step to get the answer?

Comment: @FunnyPlanks: it's the same as on the left !

Comment: Ohh yea, I understand now! We only need to minus (1/2)(2/2 + 3/4 + 4/8 + ...) on both sides, thus forming S/2 on the LHS; while (2/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...) on the RHS forms 3/2... This is truly remarkable! Thanks for your insight. :D

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
(1-x)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
$$
and differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ yields
$$
(1-x)^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = x \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

!

I solved the problem by applying the concept used in this another question.

Concerning the current problem, by making x equal to 1/2, and factorizing x in one term, and plugging x value back in, you will get 3 as the final answer

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZtwG.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 0):

!

Concerning the current problem, by making x equal to 1/2, and factorizing x in one term, and plugging x value back in, you will get 3 as the final answer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBur.jpg)[image]