# Calculate sum of a row $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left (2k-1\right )/2^k$

Tags: summation

Please help to solve:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left (2k-1\right )/2^k$
I tried to separate the numerator into $2k$ and $-1$, and the second fraction is easy to calculate. But I can't get sum for the first one.

I know the answer $3-(2n+3)/2^n$ , but can't get a solution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001506/a-problem-related-to-arithmetico-geometric-sequence/3523073#3523073

Comment: I've tried that either. No success.

Comment: What you are looking for is the [sum of AGP](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\ \frac k{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\ \left(\frac k{2^{k-1}}-\frac {k+1}{2^k}+\frac 1{2^k}\right)=1-\frac {n+1}{2^n}+\sum_{k=1}^n\ \frac 1{2^k}=2-\frac {n+2}{2^n}$$

So the required sum is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2^{k}} = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}=4-\frac{2n+4}{2^{n}}-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=3-\frac{2n+3}{2^n}$$